# How to correctly serialize/deserialize with Gson a complex object in kotlin?

Tags: android, json, serialization, kotlin, gson

I have the following fields for a JSON string:

```
action=surveyEventName
EventObject= serialized Event object (So in this field I want to serialize an object with Gson.
```

The problem I have is that when I try to serialize the Event object I get an ANR. So, I think I might be doing something wrong in terms of setting up Gson serialize.

the event class is defined this way:

```
class Event {

private var mActionName = ""
private var mId = ""
private lateinit var mConditions: MutableList<(Unit) -> Boolean>
private lateinit var mActions: MutableList<(Unit) -> Boolean>

fun getActionName(): String {
    return this.mActionName
}

fun setActionName(actionName: String) {
    this.mActionName = actionName
}

fun getId(): String {
    return this.mId
}

fun setId(id: String) {
    this.mId = id
}

fun addSingleCondition(condition: (Unit) -> Boolean) {
    if(::mConditions.isInitialized) {
        mConditions.add(condition)
    } else {
        mConditions = mutableListOf(condition)
    }
}

fun addSingleAction(action: (Unit) -> Boolean) {
    if(::mActions.isInitialized) {
        mActions.add(action)
    } else {
        mActions = mutableListOf(action)
    }
}

companion object {
    fun serializeEventList(event: List<Event>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(event) // ANR HERE!
    }

    fun deserializeEventList(jsonString: String): MutableList<Event> {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString,
                object : TypeToken<List<Event>>() {}.type)
    }
}
}
```

So then I want my final JSON, as described above to have an action tag and a serialized list of event objects. The problem I have is that when I try to serialize the list I get an ANR.

Here is my test block:

```
//TESTBLOCK
fun testEvent() {
    //create test event
    val event = Event()
    event.setId("1")
    event.setActionName("testtag")
    event.addSingleCondition { testCondition1() }
    event.addSingleCondition { testCondition2() }
    event.addSingleAction { testAction1() }
    event.addSingleAction { testAction2() }
    val events = listOf(event)
    //create test JSON
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("tagfield", "testtag")
    val serializedObjectString = event.serializeEventList(events) 
    jsonObject.put("eventobjectfield", serializedObjectString)

}
```

afterwards I deserialize the JSON eventobjectfield to make use of the Event object again, but when I try to serialize I get the ANR.

I'm not sure is Gson is not working because of the lambdas I've added to the Event object. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue with a few implementations until I realized that Gson works better if you are cautious at the moment of using it. Two things I discovered which didn't work well in my code were:

1) lateinit var: For some reason Gson hangs when parsing a class with these variables.
2) Inheritance of member variables or properties with overriden values: Basically,

if I override an inherited value Gson complains that I have two variables defined with the same name example below:

```
open class Person() {
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}

class AdultPerson() : Person() {
    override var age = 18
}
```

There Gson  will complain that the object has 2 variables with the same name age. So to solve that I would have to change the default value of age in constructor block or init block to not override the variable.

So, taking care of these two things I've managed to make Gson convert my objects to strings, even if they have complicated inheritance, Collections, or classes with variables that are Collections.

I have optimized my previous Gson parser to make it work with other classes, so far it's working fine:

GsonParser.kt

```
object GsonParser {
    inline fun <reified T> toJson(src: T): String {
        return Gson().toJson(src)
    }

    inline fun <reified T> fromJson(src: String): T {
        val type = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(src, type)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!